# Check if HTTPS (Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure) url is valid

Tags: r

How can I check if a https url is valid?

Using:

```
RCurl::url.exists("https://github.com/")
```

gives `[1] FALSE`.

I prefer base R for my needs but am not married to it.  Plus additional answers make this question more generalizable.

Comment: That code returns TRUE to me.

Comment: It returns TRUE also to me. RCurl_1.95-4.3, R 3.1.2, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please see chapter 8 of this [https://books.google.com/books?id=6k7IfACN_P8C&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437&dq=Validating+URLs+becomes+useful+only+when+we+know+the+context+in+which+those+URLs+have+to+be+valid.&source=bl&ots=CpGc3Joo4H&sig=_TJ-TBYy-lZ2egIYEoWQWkQc_2A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dbDgVKmnOtH7gwSur4ToDA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Validating%20URLs%20becomes%20useful%20only%20when%20we%20know%20the%20context%20in%20which%20those%20URLs%20have%20to%20be%20valid.&f=false] (book). I think this is also applicable to R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `httr` instead. I'm not sure which one is preferable between `url_ok` and `url_success` but they both work at this level.

```
library(httr)
url_ok("http://github.com/")
#[1] TRUE
url_ok("https://github.com/")
#[1] TRUE
url_ok("https://github.com/nonworking")
#[1] FALSE
url_success("http://github.com/")
#[1] TRUE
url_success("https://github.com/")
#[1] TRUE
url_success("https://github.com/nonworking")
#[1] FALSE
```

For some reason, `RCurl` doesn't like github even in http mode. I suspect it's because of a redirect.

```
library(RCurl)
url.exists("http://github.com/")
#[1] FALSE
url.exists("https://github.com/")
#[1] FALSE
```

Edit: Some commenters have mentionned they get TRUE as an answer, but I also get FALSE using RCurl. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Same with Windows, sounds like the common denominator

Comment: Things seem to have changed quite a bit since this pose. First on a funny note "https://github.com/nonworking" now exists. Then the `url_ok` and `url_success` functions are deprecated and we should now use `httr::http_error` (`TRUE` when error). And finally, `Rcurl` works just fine on the `github addresses`.